# Sorting days of the week with a PHP sort function

Tags: php, sorting, user-defined-functions

I am building a function to sort the days of the week based on the start day.

For example:

```
$days = array(0=>'monday',1=>'tuesday',2=>'wednesday',3=>'thursday',4=>'friday',5=>'saturday',6=>'sunday');
$startday = 1;
```

How do we get the array sorted so that the first key corresponds to tuesday (the startday), followed by wednesday, thursday, etc. ?

Currently I am using the uksort function but I am not completely certain how this would sort the array in the right way.

```
function sortbystartday($a,$b) {

 global $startday;

 if($a > $startday) return -1;

 return 1;
}

uksort($days,'sortbystartday');
```

Maybe a user defined sort function is not the right choice to do the job. So any alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother sorting, just manipulate the array as necessary.

Untested, but *should* work:

```
$new_days = array_merge(array_slice($days,$startday),array_slice($days,0,$startday));
```

Note: this will not retain the key values, so if you need that let me know and I will modify.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! The key values don't need to be retained.